NestJS try catch error handling best practice
In my NestJS application I have two services, one for user and another for authentication:
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    private readonly prismaService: PrismaService,
  ) {}
  async createUser(user: User): Promise<User> {
    try {
      return await this.prismaService.user.create(user);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Failed to create user');
    }
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private readonly usrService: UserSrvice,
  ) {}
  async register(user: User): Promise<User> {
    try {
      return await this.userService.create(user);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Failed to register User');
    }
  }
}

Do I need to use try/catch block in both services, or is it enough using only in user service?

Why catch it in either? You don't appear to be able to do anything about it, all you're doing is suppressing the rest of the traceback and making it harder to debug later on.

@jonrsharpe What is you suggestion in this situation? Please be more explicit? When should i use try catch and when to avoid? What should i change? Refer to my scenario please :)

My suggestion is: don't catch an error you can't do anything about. You might as well just let it propagate. (This is not specific to NextJS, or even JavaScript.) If you just catch { throw new Error("...") } all you achieve is dropping the original cause and context.

@jonrsharpe The more specific error message is rather useful. Users need to be told that they "failed to register", not that there was an sql transaction failure or syntax error or unreachable database server or whatever. To avoid dropping the original cause and make debugging/logging easier, use error cause: catch(cause) { throw new Error("Failed to register", { cause }); }

@Bergi it might be useful to provide that message somewhere, but we're not seeing the controller which is where the outcome would get turned into a response. And the OP isn't actually looking at the error to understand that additional context anyway; it's just getting completely flattened to new Error('Failed to register User') (potentially twice!)

@jonrsharpe Yes, agreed they shouldn't be doing that. Just  saying that instead of dropping it altogether, using error.cause is a good alternative. And you're right it's necessary probably only in the controller, not in the auth service and user service and prisma service and every other service in between.

If you want to write these try/catch blocks for logging purposes, the best way to do that is to create a logger in the constructor of every service that you create, and log the error every time you catch it.
Keep in mind that the user does not have to know that your database is down of that you have failed to execute a database join that you did not test before pushing to production. (not an offense, happened to me multiple times)
P.S. For production purposes, you can create and implement a custom class (e.g. CustomApiHttpException) that extends NestJS`s HttpException class and throw it in the code every time (as an error) you want to send a custom message to the user (e.g. "A user with this username already exists."). Then, create a custom exception filter that checks if the error that is being thrown is the instance of CustomApiHttpException (or any other class that you created) OR an uncaught error (instanceof Error). Then, you can either log the exception if you need (you almost always want to log the error with a custom logger if the error is an instance of the Error class), or skip the logging and just return the response with your custom error message to the user.

No, only one try/catch is sufficient. I would choose the one based by error handling from other parts of your codebase for consistency.
Only the latest error message will be visible on the client side (from the register) in your current code.
